# SO_SNDBUF and SO_RCVBUF settings for UDP

Tags: udp

SO_SNDBUF and SO_RCVBUF are difined as per socket buffer size.
But in case of UDP server socket does that means that its overall size for all destinations communicating with that socket , or its a size of single connection from remote address.

Example:
User A is sending data from 3.3.3.3 Port 50000 to server 1.1.1.1 on port 1234

User B is sending data from 4.4.4.4 Port 50000 to server 1.1.1.1 on port 1234

User C is sending data from 5.5.5.5 Port 50000 to server 1.1.1.1 on port 1234

There is single server socket as you see.If SO_SNDBUF and SO_RCVBUF are set to 32KB does that means that total send buffers size and total receive buffer size on server would be 32KB or 96KB?

Answer (score 1):

In the case of UDP, there are no connections, so 'single connection from remote address' has no meaning.

Comment: Hello
There may be logical connection , and you can see in netstat socket other side address on client.
As for java you can initiate connect operation which will set the remote address.

http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#connect%28java.net.InetAddress,%20int%29

However the question is about the buffers are they overall or per destination.
Best regards
Yulian Oifa

Comment: There is we've no actual connection. It's only an artifice of the local API. For instance, one end may be. 'Connected' while the other is not. Either way your question is basically meaningless. If this end is connected, nobody else can send or be sent to, so of course the buffers apply only to the connect target. If not, not.